# Virtual Method calling another virtual method in a templatized class

Tags: c++, templates, virtual-functions, class-template

I've been reading different questions on this topic, but haven't been able to find one that quite answers what I'm looking for.  Here's the pattern of code that I have:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual void foo(int) const {...}
}

template <class T>
class TmplClass : public Base {
public:
    virtual void foo(int i) const { foo(T(i)); }
    virtual void foo(T& param) const {
        printf("Template::Foo\n");
        bar(param);
    }
    virtual void bar(T&) const {
        printf("Template::Bar\n");
    }
}

class Derived : public TmplClass<SomeConcreteType> {
public:
    void bar(SomeConcreteType&) {
        printf("Derived::Bar\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    Derived d;
    Base* b = &d;
    b->foo(1);
}
```

On execution I get:

```
Template::Foo
Template::Bar
```

Why doesn't the run-time dispatch on the call to bar work?  If I overload foo in Derived then it does call the derived version of foo, why can't it do the dynamic dispatch for bar?

Because I'm working in existing code, I would prefer not to change the basic structure of the classes here.  I'm hoping to just find a way to make the call work, or understand why it doesn't.  I've tried lots of different things based on reading other questions here, but all to no avail.

Comment: Where is `Base` in  `Derived`'s ancestry?

Comment: This doesn't look like a working example. `void foo(void)` method doesn't exist, `Base` is not the ancestor class of anything. Please provide working code.

Comment: It doesn't work because this code does not compile. [This similar program](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f97076ef0ad89f1f) compiles and runs ok, though.

Comment: Sorry, the TmplClass was missing the ": public Base".  And, turns out the template issue was a red herring.  In the actual code, my Derived::Bar definition was not marked const where-as the TmplClass::Bar was, so I wasn't actually overriding the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this wasn't a template issue.  The problem with the code is that the Derived::bar method is not marked as const where-as the TmplClass::bar method is marked const.  So, the intention was to provide an over-ride, but actually Derived::bar is a totally different method with a different signature, so that's why it was giving un-expected behavior.  Once the const is removed from TmplClass::bar or added to the Derived::bar then the signatures match and the expected output is received:

```
Template::Foo
Derived::Bar
```